# Extracting numbers from a PostRequest

Tags: vb.net, http

I am posting a web form using `postreq()` in VB.NET.

The `Response` contains a string, `"sessionId=WXYZ"`, where *`WXYZ`* is 4 digits. How can I extract these numbers?

Here's my code:

```
Public Sub btn1_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    Dim postData As String = "some Post Data"
    Dim url as String = "http://localhost/form.php"
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
    postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postReq.Referer = url
    postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
    postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

    postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
    logincookie = tempCookies
    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("sessionId=....")    
End Sub
```

Comment: The regular expression you have should work; what specifically is going wrong? (Or is your question on the use of a `Regex` object?)

Comment: Yeah its Ok But i Just Want to Grep the Integer Part.  
What I want to do Something Like "grep -oE '([0-9]{4})' File".

Answer (score 1):

Just put that part in a group, so you can get its value using the [`Groups` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) of the match object:

```
Dim r As New Regex("sessionId=(\d{4})")
Dim id As String = r.Match(thepage).Groups(1).Value
```

Comment: Thanx minitech It was Bigtech From you..:)  
Keep Breathing